# Grouping Double using java 8 by arbitrary interval to Map

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

I have data which is represented as a list of positive double numbers, and a list containing the intervals which will be used to group the data. The interval is always sorted.
I tried to group the data with the following implementation

```
    List<Double> data = DoubleStream.generate(new Random()::nextDouble).limit(10).map(d -> new Random().nextInt(30) * d).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    HashMap<Integer, List<Double>> groupped = new HashMap<Integer, List<Double>>();
    data.stream().forEach(d -> {
        groupped.merge(getGroup(d, group), new ArrayList<Double>(Arrays.asList(d)), (l1, l2) -> {
            l1.addAll(l2);
            return l1;
        });
    });
    public static Integer getGroup(double data, List<Integer> group) {

    for (int i = 1; i < group.size(); i++) {
        if (group.get(i) > data) {
            return group.get(i - 1);
        }
    }
    return group.get(group.size() - 1);
}
    public static List<Integer> group() {
       List<Integer> groups = new LinkedList<Integer>();
       //can be arbitrary groupping
       groups.add(0);
       groups.add(6);
       groups.add(11);
       groups.add(16);
       groups.add(21);
       groups.add(26);
       return groups;
   }
```

Is it possible to perform this kind of groupping/reducing by performing directly the logic on data, through collectors?

In addition, thinking about the complexity of the process, this should take n^2 since we iterate over two list (or stream). Now it's not in parallel but i think it's possible to perform getGroup() in paralel. Any Insight should TreeSet or List should be used for better performance?

Comment: Note that you don't need to *stream* to do a *foreach* as it is part of `Iterable` interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`TreeSet.ceiling()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#ceiling-E-) to find the "group" boundary value.

*Example*

```
TreeSet<Double> groups = new TreeSet<>();
groups.add( 5d);                      // [-Inf,    5]
groups.add(10d);                      // ]   5,   10]
groups.add(15d);                      // ]  10,   15]
groups.add(20d);                      // ]  15,   20]
groups.add(25d);                      // ]  20,   25]
groups.add(30d);                      // ]  25,   30]
groups.add(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY); // ]  30, +Inf]

Random rnd = new Random();
for (double value = 0d; value <= 30d; value += 5d) {
    double down = Math.nextDown(value);
    double up = Math.nextUp(value);
    System.out.printf("%-18s -> %4s     %-4s -> %4s     %-18s -> %4s%n",
                      down, groups.ceiling(down),
                      value, groups.ceiling(value),
                      up, groups.ceiling(up));
}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    double value = rnd.nextDouble() * 30d;
    double group = groups.ceiling(value);
    System.out.printf("%-18s -> %4s%n", value, group);
}
```

*Output*

```
-4.9E-324          ->  5.0     0.0  ->  5.0     4.9E-324           ->  5.0
4.999999999999999  ->  5.0     5.0  ->  5.0     5.000000000000001  -> 10.0
9.999999999999998  -> 10.0     10.0 -> 10.0     10.000000000000002 -> 15.0
14.999999999999998 -> 15.0     15.0 -> 15.0     15.000000000000002 -> 20.0
19.999999999999996 -> 20.0     20.0 -> 20.0     20.000000000000004 -> 25.0
24.999999999999996 -> 25.0     25.0 -> 25.0     25.000000000000004 -> 30.0
29.999999999999996 -> 30.0     30.0 -> 30.0     30.000000000000004 -> Infinity
3.7159199611763514 ->  5.0
7.685306184937567  -> 10.0
2.6949924484301633 ->  5.0
17.594251973883363 -> 20.0
24.005899441664994 -> 25.0
7.720531186142164  -> 10.0
22.82402791692674  -> 25.0
22.68288732263466  -> 25.0
13.056624829892243 -> 15.0
8.504511505971251  -> 10.0
```

Answer (score 5):

There are plenty of improvements you can apply on your code. `Random` supports `Stream` API. So no need to generate your own `DoubleStream`.
Next you should generate your boundary set only once.
Last thing there is a `Collector::groupingBy` which does the job for you.

---

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NavigableSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String... args) {
    Random r = new Random();
    List<Double> data = r.doubles(10).map(d -> r.nextInt(30) * d).peek(System.out::println).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    NavigableSet<Integer> groups = group();
    Map<Integer, List<Double>> groupped = data.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d -> groups.floor(d.intValue()), TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
    System.out.println(groupped);
  }

  public static NavigableSet<Integer> group() {
    NavigableSet<Integer> groups = new TreeSet<>();
    groups.add(0);
    groups.add(6);
    groups.add(11);
    groups.add(16);
    groups.add(21);
    groups.add(26);
    return groups;
  }
}
```